# Best Practices for Versioning Maven Multimodule Projects in Git

Tags: git, maven

Got a Maven multimodule project. Some parts evolve more frequently than others. If all modules get the same version numbers a lot of space is wasted for the slow-evolving modules.

Different versions for modules are difficult to handle.

Should modules go into different Git projects?

Comment: Space is wasted where?

Comment: I mean the resulting target jars which end up in Nexus.

Comment: Do you know about https://github.com/mojohaus/versions-maven-plugin?

Comment: First if you are very accurate you are correct about wasting some space (have you ever calculated the size of that space ?) Based on that it means either extract those parts into a separate standalone project (git repo) with separate release cycle and maintain the dependency version . Or you go the way to waste that space and make a simple clean release and use alway the same version which is supported out of the box via maven-release-plugin or if you don't like use versions-maven-plugin and some part in Jenkins (to create your tags) or https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit unclear but I try to answer:

1. Git does not copy your whole repository when you check in. You do not waste space by having everything in the same git repository.
2. For Maven versions, things are different: If you build every module in every build process but only change one module, you end up with a lot of jars that have the same content. This clearly wastes space in your Maven repository (Nexus/Artifactory). Having different versions for different modules may be more appropriate.

Comment: For different versions for diffent modules I have to modify version numbers in pom files by hand, there is no plugin that helps, is it?

Comment: What exactly do you expect from that plugin? Usually, if you change the code of an artifact, you need to change the version number on 1st, 2nd or 3rd place according to whether the change is major, minor or a bugfix. What automatisation do you have in mind?

Comment: Well, the Versions Maven Plugin updates all child module versions automatically.

Comment: You mean the dependencies from one module to another module? Use properties for the version numbers.